# How to replace alert with modal in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do you make a modal pop-up without clicking a button in react native? I am currently using an alert to pop -up once the game state changes but I'd like to be able to style it so I want to change it to a modal view. I'm not sure how to implement it into my code :( Could someone please teach me how?

```
  const checkGameState = () => {
    if (gameWon()) {
      setGameState('won')
      Alert.alert('You won!', [
        { text: 'play again', onPress: () => newGame() }
      ])
    } else if (gameLost()) {
      setGameState('lost')
      Alert.alert('You Lost', [
        { text: 'try again', onPress: () => newGame() }
      ])
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use react-native-modalize for easy modals, this saved me alot of hours and pain.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

const modal = useRef(null);

const verifyBeforeSend = () => {
    modal.current?.open();
}


return (
    // your screen content

        <Modalize adjustToContentHeight ref={modal}>

        // your modal content

        </Modalize>

    // your screen content
)
```

I guess this is you were looking for

Comment: how do i implement this into the gameState variable?

Comment: Put {   stateCondition&& component}

Answer (score 0):

You can create GlobalModal at App.js, using ref = createRef()
when you want call it, you can call ref.current.open(...) everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You could use react native's modal component to get your custom styling. You would need to create a context to be able to easily access the alert parameters, and then create a hook to  update those parameters ([demo](https://snack.expo.dev/cMC_WhLos)):

Context:

```js
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
// i like to handle all global context stuff in a single file
// e.g. navigationcontainer, gesturehandler root view, etc

export const AlertContext = createContext({
  title: '',
  message: '',
  buttons: [],
  visible: false,
  setAlertParams: () => {},
});

export default function ContextContainer({ children }) {
  const [alertParams, setAlertParams] = useState({
    title: '',
    message: '',
    buttons: [],
    visible: false,
  });
 
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider
      value={{ ...alertParams, setAlertParams }}>
      <>
        {children}
        <Alert />
      </>
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Alert Component:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  useWindowDimensions,
  Modal,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import { AlertContext } from '../Context';
import ModalButton from './ModalButton'
export default function Alert() {
  const {
    title,
    message,
    buttons,
    visible,
    setAlertParams,
    closeAlert
  } = useContext(AlertContext);
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const modalWidth = width * 0.8;
  const modalHeight = width * 0.8;
  
  return (
    <Modal visible={visible} transparent>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.modalContainer,
          {
            width: modalWidth,
            //height: modalHeight,
            top: height * 0.25,
            left: width * 0.1,
          },
        ]}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <View style={styles.messageView}>
          <Text style={styles.message}>{message}</Text>
        </View>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.buttonRowContainer,
            {
              width: modalWidth - styles.modalContainer.padding * 2,
            },
          ]}>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
            contentContainerStyle={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}
            data={buttons}
            horizontal
            renderItem={ModalButton}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  titleRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  buttonRowContainer: {
    marginVertical: 4,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  message: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  messageView: {
    marginVertical: 5,
    padding: 5,
  },
});
```

Hook:

```js
import { useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import { AlertContext } from '../Context';

export default function useAlert() {
  const { setAlertParams } = useContext(AlertContext);
  const closeAlert = useCallback(() => {
    setAlertParams((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, visible: false };
    });
  }, [setAlertParams]);
  const showAlert = useCallback(
    (title, message, buttons, hideCloseButton) => {
      buttons = buttons || [];
      if (buttons.length == 0) {
        buttons = [{ title: 'Ok', onPress: closeAlert }];
      }
      if (!hideCloseButton)
        buttons.push({ title: 'Cancel', onPress: closeAlert });
      setAlertParams({ title, message, buttons, visible: true });
    },
    [closeAlert, setAlertParams]
  );
  return { closeAlert, showAlert };
}
```

Usage:

```js
import {useContext} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {AlertContext} from '../Context'
import useAlert from '../hooks/useAlert'
const alertButtons = Array(3).fill(null).map((_,index)=>{
  const num = index+1
  return {
    title:"Button "+ num,
    onPress:()=>console.log("Button",num, "was pressed")
  }
})

export default function App() {
  const { showAlert, closeAlert } = useAlert();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Just a normal screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Open Alert"
          onPress={() =>
            showAlert(
              'Testing alert',
              'There should be a message in the alert',
              alertButtons
            )
          }
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```